# How to use a OpenVPN network interface without redirecting everything over it?

Tags: networking, openvpn, linux-networking

I am using an OpenVPN server I have no control over that has provided me with a client configuration to use. When I use the provided configuration, everything works as expected - all the network traffic on my local machine gets redirected through the VPN connection.

I want to figure out how to use the tunnel network interface without redirecting all traffic through it.

**My setup**

I have a software that performs a series of tasks and supports specifying the exact network interface to perform those tasks on. I want to be able to specify the `tun01` OpenVPN interface on this software without affecting anything else on the machine.

Moreover, I need to be able to set up multiple VPNs over different network interfaces - `tun01`, `tun02`, `tun03` etc. - so I can run my software doing simultaneous, separate tasks over each interface.

**The problem**

Right now I'm setting up all the separate network interfaces, but only the first OpenVPN to start up is actually working. My hunch is that the following OpenVPN clients I start are trying to tunnel through the first one instead of using my regular connection.

Basically, I need to either make the default state for my network to NOT tunnel through the OpenVPN so I can select the actual network interface I need to use manually, or find a way to make the OpenVPN client to ignore previous active VPN connections.

**What I've tried already**

My best attempt so far was to include `pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway` in my configuration file in hopes of not getting the routes installed and then using the `tun01` interface directly, but when I tried doing that, the connection on my software did not use the VPN, instead using my regular connection.

Answer (score 1):

> My best attempt so far was to include `pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway` in my configuration file in hopes of not getting the routes installed and then using the `tun01` interface directly, but when I tried doing that, the connection on my software did not use the VPN, instead using my regular connection.

Yes, what did you expect? The configuration you got uses pull, which pulls a default route (among other things). You blocked getting the default route, so your default route is not modified. If you don't want the default route the server sends, then you have to add routing entries for those addresses to want to direct to the VPN server.